# Set focus to content of ContentPresenter

Tags: wpf, focus, contentpresenter

I need to set focus to the content of a `ContentPresenter`. I can assume the `ContentTemplate` contains an IInputElement but not anything else about it.

Here is a much simplified example that illustrates the problem:

Main window:

```
<Window x:Class="FiedControlTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:Esatto.Wpf.CustomControls;assembly=Esatto.Wpf.CustomControls"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FiedControlTest">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Options}" Name="cbOptions" DisplayMemberPath="Description"/>
            <Button Content="Set focus" Click="SetFocus"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="TextBox:"/>
            <TextBox Name="tbText" Text="A bare text box."/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="ContentPresenter:"/>
            <ContentPresenter Content="TextBox in a ContentPresenter" Name="cpText">
                <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
            </ContentPresenter>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Codebehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.DataContext = this;
        Options = new ObservableCollection<Option>(new[]{
            new Option(){TargetType=typeof(TextBox), Description="Bare Text Box"},
            new Option(){TargetType=typeof(ContentPresenter), Description="Content Presenter"}
        });
        InitializeComponent();
        cbOptions.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void SetFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var opt = cbOptions.SelectedItem as Option;
        if (opt.TargetType == typeof(TextBox))
            tbText.Focus();
        if (opt.TargetType == typeof(ContentPresenter))
            cpText.Focus();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Option> Options { get; set; }

    public class Option
    {
        public Type TargetType { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

There's not much there. The bare `TextBox` takes focus as expected; the `TextBox` presented by the `ContentPresenter` does not.

I have tried adding `Focusable="True"` to the `ContentPresenter` but it doesn't have any visible effect. I've tried doing using `Keyboard.SetFocus` instead of `UIElement.Focus` but the behavior doesn't change.

How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact what you set focus is the `ContentPresenter`, not the inner `TextBox`. So you can use `VisualTreeHelper` to find the child visual element (the TextBox in this case) and set focus for it. However with `IsReadOnly` being `true`, you won't see any caret blinking (which may also be what you want). To show it in readonly mode, we can just set `IsReadOnlyCaretVisible` to `true`:

```
private void SetFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var opt = cbOptions.SelectedItem as Option;
    if (opt.TargetType == typeof(TextBox))
        tbText.Focus();
    if (opt.TargetType == typeof(ContentPresenter)) {
       var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(cpText, 0) as TextBox;
       if(child != null) child.Focus();
    }            
}
```

Here the edited XAML code with `IsReadOnlyCaretVisible` added:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" 
         IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="True"/>
```

Note that the above code can only be applied in your specific case where you use a `TextBox` as the root visual of ContentTemplate of a ContentPresenter. In general case, you will need some recursive method to find the child visual (based on `VisualTreeHelper`), you can search more for this, I don't want to include it here because it's a very well-known problem/code in WPF to *find visual child* in WPF. (the italic phrase can be used as keywords to search for more).

Comment: I must not have written clearly. I don't care about the background color; that's just there as an indicator to make it easier to see at a glance where focus is. I *am* interested in actually getting keyboard focus onto that textbox, not the content presenter.

Comment: @mcwyrm I agree that your question was confusing, please see my updated answer.